# 2D Platformer multiple classes without code duplication

Tags: c#

I'm working on a 2D platformer in c#, as most people are, but I have got a decent start to the project I have a class called Player, I then handle all collision for that player as well as the scrolling of the blocks in the background within the gamescreen class. I have just added another player (as a different class in this case a warrior), but all of my collision is based around the players positions and velocity, how would I change the blocks movement and collision to be around the warrior's velocity and positions instead (without duplicating or creating quite a lot of code).

Thanks for any help Sam.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is your friend.  You should probably have a base Player class, or even something more low level than that.  The base class implements the colision detection and movement code.  Your Warrior and other player types should inherit that class and override different parts to change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

My strategy works approximately like this:

I have a `Character` class. It contains a `HitboxSet`. The `HitboxSet` exposes an active `Hitbox`. All my collision is done based on `Hitbox` instances. Depending on what kind of character I need, I pass in different sprites, hitboxes, movements, etc.

The result is a high degree of flexibility, while allowing you to keep your concerns thoroughly separated. This strategy is known as Composition, and is widely considered superior to inheritance based strategies in almost all cases.

The main advantage of this strategy over inheritance is the ability to mix and match components. If, one day, you decide that you need a new projectile that's smaller than a previous one, and moves in a sine pattern, you simply use a new sine movement. You can reuse such things infinitely, in any combination.

You can do something like this with inheritance: a child class can override a method and do something differently. The problem is that you either keep adding new child classes with different combinations and end up with a terrifyingly complex tree, or you limit your options.

In short, if something is naturally going to vary, as it almost certainly will in a game, those variations should be distinct classes that can be combined in different ways rather than mutually exclusive overrides.